# How to use entry widgets in Tkinter in a loop

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, widget

I'm creating a Mad Libs game that has a lot of user inputs. I created a function to get all inputs in a list, given a list of the word types. There's no error message, but the window is blank. I tried printing the wordInputs list, and it comes up with:

> [<bound method StringVar.get of <tkinter.StringVar object at 0x108763fd0>>,

and so forth. I presume this is because it deleted all of the widgets, but I figured it would do that only after I typed them in. I'm not exactly sure how to store the input into a variable either; do I create a button for that or something? Here's the code:

```
from tkinter import *

class Game:
    #Gets user input for a specified type of word
    def getWord(self, words):
        wordInputs = []
        for i in range(len(words)):
            frame = Frame(self.windowSnowDay)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text = "\nSnow Day\n________\n").grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
            Label(frame, text = "Enter a(n) " + words[i] + ":").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
            word = StringVar()
            Entry(frame, textvariable = word).grid(row = i + 2, column = 2)
            wordInputs.append(word.get)
            frame.destroy()
        return wordInputs

    #Executes "Snow Day" story from Mad Libs menu
    def snowDay(self):
        self.windowMadLibs.destroy()
        self.windowSnowDay = Tk()
        self.windowSnowDay.title("Snow Day")
        self.windowSnowDay.geometry("200x200")
        frame = Frame(self.windowSnowDay)
        frame.pack()
        #Collects words and stores them in a list
        words = ["verb", "electronic device", "public place", "adjective", "verb ending with -ing", "color", "noun", "noun", "drink", \
            "clothing item", "adjective", "3-dimensional shape", "adjective", "plural noun", "adjective", "feeling (adjective)", "food"]
        wordInputs = self.getWord(words)
        print(wordInputs)
        self.windowSnowDay.mainloop()
        #Prints "Snow Day" story with all inputted words
        print("\nAll the children cheer in", emotion, "as they", verb, "that morning. They hear on the", device,"that the", place, end =' ')
        print("is closed because of a snowstorm. They think of all the", adj, "things they could do today, such as", verb1, "on a", end = ' ')
        print(color, noun + ". Maybe they can even make a snow" + noun1 + "! They go inside, where a warm cup of", drink, "awaits", end = ' ')
        print("them. Before going outside, they put on their scarves and", clothing, "so that they don't get", adj1 + ". They", end = ' ')
        print("make a snow" + noun1, "out of 3 large", shape + "s, but it quickly fell apart because the snow wasn't very", adj2, end = '. ')
        print("After that, one of the", noun2, "attacked another, and it turned into a", adj3, "snowball fight. They were so", feeling, end = ' that ')
        print("they went straight to bed. Oh well, I guess they can eat the leftovers of Mom's famous", food, "tomorrow!")

    #Main function for Mad Libs
    def madLibs(self):
        self.windowMadLibs = Tk()
        self.windowMadLibs.title("Mad Libs")
        self.windowMadLibs.geometry("200x200")
        frame = Frame(self.windowMadLibs)
        frame.pack()
        Label(frame, text = "\nMad Libs\n________\n").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Button(frame, text = "Snow Day", command = self.snowDay).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.windowMadLibs.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main issue is it does not wait for user input, so it's basically going through the loop with all blank values in the entry, then nothing is filled.
(See my comments in the code for more detail)

The `bound method StringVar.get` result is from `wordInputs.append(word.get)` instead of `wordInputs.append(word.get())`

Also, multiple `Tk()` and `.mainloop()` calls tend to gum up the works.

This will get it going again, but window re-sizing will need to be addressed,

**The prints reference variables that will need to be filled in, you may want a `dictionary` versus a `list`:**

```
from tkinter import *

class Game:
    #Gets user input for a specified type of word
    def getWord(self, words):           
        wordInputs = []
        for i in range(len(words)):
            frame = Frame(self.windowSnowDay)
            frame.pack()
            Label(frame, text = "\nSnow Day\n________\n").grid(row = 1, column = 1, columnspan = 2)
            Label(frame, text = "Enter a(n) " + words[i] + ":").grid(row = 2, column = 1)
            word = StringVar()
            entry = Entry(frame)
            entry.grid(row = i + 2, column = 2)
            button = Button(frame, text = "Done", command = lambda: word.set(entry.get()))
            button.grid(row = i + 3, column = 2)
            button.wait_variable(word) # waits for button to be activated and sets the variable.
            wordInputs.append(word.get())
            frame.destroy()
        return wordInputs

    #Executes "Snow Day" story from Mad Libs menu
    def snowDay(self):
        self.windowMadLibs.withdraw() # withdraw the main window.
        self.windowSnowDay = Toplevel(self.windowMadLibs) # create a Toplevel instead of a new main.
        self.windowSnowDay.title("Snow Day")
        self.windowSnowDay.geometry("200x200")
        frame = Frame(self.windowSnowDay)
        frame.pack()
        #Collects words and stores them in a list
        words = ["verb", "electronic device", "public place", "adjective", "verb ending with -ing", "color", "noun", "noun", "drink", \
            "clothing item", "adjective", "3-dimensional shape", "adjective", "plural noun", "adjective", "feeling (adjective)", "food"]
        wordInputs = self.getWord(words)
        print(wordInputs)
        #Prints "Snow Day" story with all inputted words
        print("\nAll the children cheer in", emotion, "as they", verb, "that morning. They hear on the", device,"that the", place, end =' ')
        print("is closed because of a snowstorm. They think of all the", adj, "things they could do today, such as", verb1, "on a", end = ' ')
        print(color, noun + ". Maybe they can even make a snow" + noun1 + "! They go inside, where a warm cup of", drink, "awaits", end = ' ')
        print("them. Before going outside, they put on their scarves and", clothing, "so that they don't get", adj1 + ". They", end = ' ')
        print("make a snow" + noun1, "out of 3 large", shape + "s, but it quickly fell apart because the snow wasn't very", adj2, end = '. ')
        print("After that, one of the", noun2, "attacked another, and it turned into a", adj3, "snowball fight. They were so", feeling, end = ' that ')
        print("they went straight to bed. Oh well, I guess they can eat the leftovers of Mom's famous", food, "tomorrow!")

    #Main function for Mad Libs
    def madLibs(self):
        self.windowMadLibs = Tk()
        self.windowMadLibs.title("Mad Libs")
        self.windowMadLibs.geometry("200x200")
        frame = Frame(self.windowMadLibs)
        frame.pack()
        Label(frame, text = "\nMad Libs\n________\n").grid(row = 1, column = 1)
        Button(frame, text = "Snow Day", command = self.snowDay).grid(row = 2, column = 1)
        self.windowMadLibs.mainloop()

g = Game()
g.madLibs()
```